# How to create a sidebar with react-router and style the buttons

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a sidebar with buttons as shown in the image. I want to have the button to be dark grey when it is active. I have the bootstrap code but if I apply bootstrap using the css file and javascript file in the public/index.html then the navigation bar images comes to the middle of the navigation bar so I want to use the react-bootstrap for my sidebar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjNGy.jpg

this is the bootstrap code. how do I use react router's Link instead of  tags? for react bootstrap we generally use <'Row'> <'Col'> so how do we use these many "col" classes "col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2". I'm also confused with ul tags in react-bootstrap as to how to use them with nav pills and other classes

```
<nav class="d-none d-md-block col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 sidebar">    
        <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills  nav-fill flex-column" role="tablist" style="margin-top:42px;">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#/!" style="text-align:left;">
                            <img src="/images/windows.png" style="height:20px;">
                            Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#!people" style="text-align:left;">
                                <img src="/images/people.png" style="height:20px;">                                
                            People</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

css for the sidebar

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 48px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use it replacing your "a" tag by "Link" react router tag.

E.g

```
<Link to="/target" />
```

OR

```
<Link to="/target">
  <!-- your tags come here --> 
</Link>
```

But you should avoid use css and js files in index.html. The right way is you create a new component and to style in its own scope.

As you are using react-bootstrap, you can create your component like this (for your case I think it is not necessary use many css classes. You can achieve your goal by default react-bootstrap columns):

```
<Container> // Your sidebar
  <Row>
    <Col><Link to="/path-1" /></Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Col><Link to="/path-2" /></Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Col><Link to="/path-2" /></Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

You need apply some css styles to achieve your final layout.

Comment: my main concern is the style of the left sidebar buttons. How do I achieve that style using react-bootstrap

Comment: I have not used react-bootstrap, but you can do it with only css.

[Here](https://codepen.io/raphaellima8/pen/MWgzoZg) is a pen to help you to understand a little bit how you can do it with css.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the Link component from react-router. Replace the `<a></a>` tag for the link component `<Link/>`. So where you're using:

`<a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#/!" style="text-align:left;">`

It should be:

`<Link to={"/route_that_you_want_to_go"} style={{textAlign: "left"}}> Name </Link>`

Also jsx doesn't uses `class` keyword to refer to css styles it uses `className`

For any more information, you can refer to the [react-router Link component documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md)

Comment: my main concern is the style of the left sidebar buttons. How do I achieve that style using react-bootstrap? The pill style and also the button becoming dark grey when being active and also the button flowing till the end of the window